# How to loop an Array, and to get each time the next 3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of objects like this one - `[{first},{second},{third},{forth},{fifth},{sixth}}`

How can I loop through the Array, and get (for each loop) the next three elements of that Array ?

For example, for the first loop I'll get three variables that reference to `{first}`, `{second}` and `{third}`, for the second loop I'll get variables that reference to `{forth}`, `{fifth}` and `{sixth}` ...
And so on...

Comment: Are you looking for [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)?

Comment: Addition: `i += 3`, `array[i]`, `array[i + 1]`, `array[i + 2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 3) {
    var a = arr[i];
    var b = arr[i + 1];
    var c = arr[i + 2];
    ...
}
```

Comment: @NullUserException—and what is the problem with that?

Comment: @RobG You can end up getting `undefined` elements.

Comment: @NullUserException—the OP must deal with that of course (same with missing members in sparse arrays), but it's not, of itself, an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
var array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i+=3){
    var first = array[i];
    var second = (array[i+1]) ? array[i+1] : null;
    var third = (array[i+2]) ? array[i+2] : null;
}
```

If the index does not exist in the array, the variable will be `null`.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9beKf/)

Comment: That makes no sense. If a member is missing, why is assigning a random value better than `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

Another version of the accepted answer is:

```
var i = 0, len = arr.length;
while (i < len) {
    var a = arr[i++];
    var b = arr[i++];
    var c = arr[i++];
    ...
}
```

If the array is sparse, or length is not an even multiple of 3, you may want to test that elements exist before reading their value and take that into consideration when incrementing the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
   // Loop
}
for (j = i; j < arr.length; j += 1) {
   // Second loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 for the element after i, and add 2 for the element that comes after that.

```
var ary1,ary2,ary3;

for(var i=0;i<size-3;i+=3){
  ary1 = myary[i];
  ary2 = myary[i+1];
  ary3 = myary[i+2];
}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wants non-overlapping slices.

Answer (score 0):

This is really pretty basic

```
var array; // your array (let's pretend it's already populated)

for (i = 0; i < array.length - 3; i += 3) {
    element1 = array[i];
    element2 = array[i+1];
    element3 = array[i+2];
}
```

I didn't put in handling for cases where you don't have exactly a multiple of three objects in the array, but this should get you started.